# Google auth from android app to post to google+

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-plus

I authenticate user to google with AccountManager and with scope "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login".

I've sent received token to server. Server tries to make moments.insert with my token, but it receives "code": 401, "message": "Unauthorized"

Server just uses my token an "me" as user id.

Please, help: whether problem is on server side or on client side and what is the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, you cannot post activity to Google+ programmatically. The app activities that you can write are specific to your application and appear on a user's profile but not in their stream.

To use app activities, you must request permissions for the types of app activities that you are writing and pass these to the [Google+ client's builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/PlusClient.Builder.html):

```
private PlusClient mPlusClient;

private static final String[] actions = {
    "https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/snippet/examples/thing" 
};

mPlusClient = new PlusClient.Builder(this, this, this)
    .setActions(actions)
    .build();
```

...

Comment: What I need is receiving some token I can send to server and server should be able to post to my stream on google+.

Comment: It is currently not possible to post to a user's Google+ stream without the user explicitly making the post. For this, you should be using the interactive post button - https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/interactive